# Restrict Android Market Application By Location

Tags: android, location, state, google-play, restriction

I've read that it is possible to restrict an application that you submit to the Android Market by country.  Is it possible to restrict users from downloading your application by state in the United States?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no; you can only restrict by country.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but I pretty sure there is no way to do that. The question would be what kind of parameters a wireless carrier would use to identify unique states and how it can be made available to Android platform and thus to developers. There is no easy way to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure each customer has an address registered with their wireless carrier which will include the state.  Isn't this how they tell what country you are in?

Comment: I agree that carriers probably have various mechanisms to track handsets, and even states these handsets are in. But at Android API level the information is not available. Carriers have been historically reluctant to provide this info.